# Drawing a polygon by a lot of dots

Tags: visualization, polygon, graphic

My desired output is moving a lot of dots to visualize some words.
The effect is similar to this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Le13by2WM70 .

I think this problem could be split into two sub-problem.
The first is how to extract the path from a vector font. 
The second is how to moving dots to visulize that polygon.

There are some tools could solve first part, but I have not idea about the second part.
Anyone has done this?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do pretty well by just sampling points on a regular grid, with a little jitter added in to avoid looking too computery. All you need to do is check if you are "inside" or "outside" of the path. For inside, place a fish (or dot); for outside, no fish.

Comment: I think the question is asking more for the motion part than the initialisation part, but I agree this is simpler than working out polygons.